# Mocking classes that require private autowired fields using JMockit

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jmockit

I have been stuck on this for a while, being very new to JMockit.

I have a class that I want to mock, named `ClassToMock`. `ClassToMock` looks like this,

```java
public class ClassToMock {
    @Resource(name="firstDependencyBean")
    private StandardDependency standardDependency;

    // Methods defined here, omitted for brevity
}
```

The `StandardDependency` class looks something like this,

```java
public class StandardDependency {
    @Resource(name="secondDependencyBean")
    private OtherStandardDependency otherStandardDependency;

    // Methods defined here, omitted for brevity
}
```

`OtherStandardDependency` shares a similar structure, it also having dependencies that are injected using the `@Resource` annotation.

My test class looks something like this, currently playing around with it so nothing meaningful at the moment,

```java
public class TestClass {
    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true) ClassToMock classToMock;

    @Test
    public void TestTrivialCase() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

However, when running, I get the following exception,

```bash
Missing @Tested instance of an implementation class for field "OtherStandardDependecy otherStandardDependency" StandardDependency
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing @Tested instance of an implementation class for field "OtherStandardDependecy otherStandardDependency" StandardDependency
```

So I tried this,

```java
public class TestClass {
    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true) ClassToMock classToMock;
    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true) StandardDependency standardDependency;

    @Test
    public void TestTrivialCase() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And also tried this (just tried it, not given much though),

```java
public class TestClass {
    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true) ClassToMock classToMock;
    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true) StandardDependency standardDependency;
    @Injectable OtherStandardDependency otherStandardDependency;

    @Test
    public void TestTrivialCase() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

No luck.

Any help in resolving this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a JMockit test class, you normally have a single class (classUnderTest) annotated with the "@Tested" annotation.   Any classes that class needs should be @Injectable.  e.g. classes passed to the constructor of the @Tested class, or things that are @Autowired (which I believe @Resource is an extension thereof).

So, try something like this.

```
public class TestClass {
    @Tested ClassToMock classToMock;
    @Injectable StandardDependency standardDependency;
    @Injectable OtherStandardDependency otherStandardDependency;

    @Test
    public void testConstruction() {
        assertNotNull(classToMock);
    }
}
```

As a side benefit, it should read more intuitively expressing that one class is the one being "tested" and the other elements are just there because you need them to make testing work.  All 3 classes are 'mocks' and can be accessed/utilized as such from subsequent tests.